# VM-Manager/QEMU gnome unstable

Tags: gnome, kvm-virtualization

I have some question about virt-manager and QEMU. When my host machine is on lock screen, and I logging again into my host machine. Then gnome is totally unstable.

Do somebody else have same experience, and what to do.

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: What do you mean by "totally unstable"? What exactly is happening?

Comment: Hi, it's very difficult to explain how it exactly happening that my gui behave weird and after some while time it seems that issue is fixing by self. Since I wrote didn't get issue.